# Spring MVC no default constructor found

Tags: spring, cxf

I've got a problem with this program

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cdmiService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'badRequestException' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'badRequestException' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.snia.cdmiserver.exception.BadRequestException]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.snia.cdmiserver.exception.BadRequestException.<init>()
```

and my xml is as follows:

```
 <bean id="badRequestException"     class="org.snia.cdmiserver.exception.BadRequestException"/>
```

The BadRequestException.java is as follows:

```
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
public BadRequestException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public BadRequestException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
}

public BadRequestException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
}
```

How could I solve this problem?add a default construtor or edit the xml file?

Comment: The most interesting things here is: why do you create bean with exception class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > How could I solve this problem?add a default construtor or edit the xml file?

You can solve it either way.

1. add a default construtor:

   ```
       public BadRequestException() {
          super();
       }
   ```
2. edit the xml file

   ```
   <bean id="badRequestException"     class="org.snia.cdmiserver.exception.BadRequestException">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"><value>Message you want</value></constructor-arg>
   </bean >
   ```